# specific weeks form given month

Tags: php, date

I am developing a system in which users are given a incentive based on weekly performance.
So when I pass year and month I want the first week starts form monday and last week will be that which having sunday in same month, otherwise it should be counted in next month.
For example;

if i pass `month = '03'` and `year = '2014'` I want following as weeks:

```
week 1: 2014-03-03 to 2014-03-09 // Coz 03 has first monday in a month
 week 2: 2014-03-10 to 2014-03-16
 week 3: 2014-03-17 to 2014-03-23
 week 4: 2014-03-14 to 2014-03-30
```

now, 31 has monday but doesn't have sunday in same month(march), end in april So that shold not be counted.
now if i pass $month = '04' and year = '2014'
week 1 shold be : 2014-03-31 to 2014-04-06
like wise, whenver i pass month and year i want this type of results.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again?

Comment: coz no one has helped yet!!

Comment: You got an answer four hours ago!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to invent your own week numbering system, just use the [ISO-8601 week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

In PHP you can get the current week number with `date('W')`, and you can get the week number for a specific date like so: `date('W', strtotime('2014-03-11')`. Check the documentation for [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for details.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is (pseudo code)

$h will be the last day of the month in unix format (mktime)
in numerical representation 0 is sunday

$h = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),0,date("Y"));
$w = date("w", $h) ;

if($w == 0){
   process the reward for current month
} else {
   process the reward for the next month
}

or something to that effect.   You are never going to have a sunday in the current month if the last day falls on anything but a sunday.

Not sure if that helps.  Hopefully it does and if not hopefully it starts you off right.